# How can multiple lines be copied based on a cell criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Example of the file]

How can i copy all rows automatically and multiply them according to the information found in column Q. For example i need all the informations in the 2nd row to be copy 2 times, the one in row 3 3 times, row 4 4 times, row 5 just once, and so on. Many thanks for the help

Comment: You'd probably need VBA to do that. Unfortunately, this site is not a free script order service. We're happy to help if you get stuck with your code. Just post your code and ask specifics.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy using formula you need to use Helper Column R for example, write 1 in R2
In R3 write =R2+Q2
and drag it down

If your Data is in Sheet2 and you want the result in sheet1, in column A sheet1 use a helper column:
In A2 write 1, in A3 write 2 select both and drag it down to have 1,2,3,4... in column A
In B2 write the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$P$7,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$R$2:$R$7),COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

and drag it in the same row and down you will have your Data as requested
Finally you can select the new Data copy then Paste Special Values in the final sheet